# Load View on UIButton Click

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i try to lad a UIViewController on UIButton click

GehaltVIew.m

```
#import "GehaltVIew.h"
#import "Berechnen.h"

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView *footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];

    UIButton *berechnenButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    berechnenButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40); 
    [berechnenButton setTitle:@"Berechnen!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [berechnenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(berechnenGehalt) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [footerView addSubview:berechnenButton];

    return footerView;
}


- (void)berechnenGehalt
{
    Berechnen *dvController = [[Berechnen alloc] initWithNibName:@"Berechnen" bundle:nil];

    self.view = dvController;
}
```

but i get this error:

2011-07-22 14:51:59.598 Seminar App2[33791:207] -[Berechnen setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d05bd0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this statement:

```
 Berechnen *dvController = [[Berechnen alloc] initWithNibName:@"Berechnen" bundle:nil];
```

it seems to me the `Berechnen` should be a `UIViewController`, not a `UIView`, so the next line should be:

```
self.view = dvController.view;
```

Please, also notice that in `tableView:viewForFooterInSection` you are possibly leaking `footerView`. I think that you should autorelease the footerView:

```
UIView *footerView  = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```